# Unterminated Parenthetical error with a Regular Expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use the following regular expression to validate a date in javascript (sorry it's a bit of a brute):

```
"/^(((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9][0-9])[0-9]{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9][0-9])[0-9]{2}))|((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9][0-9])[0-9]{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9][0-9])(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/"
```

The problem is, I'm getting an Unterminated Parenthetical Javascript error.  I tried using this expression in PHP with preg_match and it works fine.

A bit stumped so any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:  I should add, the date I'm trying to validate would be in a dd/mm/yyyy format.

Edit 2: Sorry, I should have clarified that I'm using the jQuery validator from position-abolute.com (http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/).
The custom rule I have defined is:

```
"date":{
    "regex":"/^(((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9][0-9])[0-9]{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9][0-9])[0-9]{2}))|((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9][0-9])[0-9]{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9][0-9])(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/",
    "alertText":"* Invalid date, must be in DD/MM/YYYY format."}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using for the validation ?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to create a Date from the components and see that it returns the same value when read?

Comment: Use a editor that highlights the pairs of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

No error in Firebug. Also *regexplanet.com* compiles this fine (once removing the forward slashes).

However, 21 capturing groups -- especially if they are nested -- are hardly the ideal approach in JavaScript. Parsing the matches will be a nightmare.

My suggestion would be to try break down your regexp into parts if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your answers.  I know using such a convuluted regex isn't ideal but I'm working on an existing system and wanted to maintain consistent validation methods.

Anyway, what was happening was the regex string was being extracted by another method before being evaluated, which removed the escaping '\' characters ('/' became '/').

The quickest solution I could think of was to replace '/' with '[/]', as the forward slash loses it's special meaning in the character set.  The regex now looks like:

```
/^(((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](0[13578]|1[02])[/]((19|[2-9][0-9])[0-9]{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)[/](0[13456789]|1[012])[/]((19|[2-9][0-9])[0-9]{2}))|((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[/]02[/]((19|[2-9][0-9])[0-9]{2}))|(29[/]02[/]((1[6-9]|[2-9][0-9])(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/
```

Hope that makes sense and thanks again!

Comment: Double escape (`\\/`) won't do it? Other than that, from your edit I gathered that you want to validate a date of some specific format. In that case I think you might be able to simplify your regexp quite a deal.

Comment: You're right, double escape is a better solution.  Not sure why I didn't think of that before the character set :S

Answer (score 0):

either use /MyRegex/ or new RegExp("myRegex")

Comment: The validation plugin apparently takes a String.

Comment: well he didn't point out that he's using a validation plugin till recently. But still either // or "" both is plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The regex looks good parenthetical wise, but I suggest you use non-capturing groups (?: ) where you do not need to capture anything. Additionally in case you might not know you can check http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for more info.